# Python map data frame to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dict with this structure

```
dict={'1': 'AA',
 '2': 'GG',
 '3': 'AA',
 '4': 'CC',
 '5': 'TT',
 '6': 'AA',
 '7': 'TT',
 '8': 'GG',
 '9': 'CT',
 '10': 'AA',}
```

and data frame

```
df
VALUE RS TYPE CONDITION OTHER_COLUMN OTHER-COLUMN
SS 2 GG PROB 1 2
SS 2 GA INTER 1 2
SS 2 AA NORMAL 1 2
DD 9 CC PROB 1 2
DD 9 CT NORMAL 1 2
DD 9 TT INTER 1 2
FF 5 TT PROB 1 2
FF 5 TG INTER 1 2
FF 5 GG NORMAL 1 1
```

the dict has 100000  key's and values, and dataframe 300 rows, I want to print only that row that are coincident between dataframe and dict for example.

```
VALUE RS TYPE CONDITION OTHER_COLUMN OTHER-COLUMN    
SS 2 GG PROB 1 2
DD 9 CT NORMAL 1 2
FF 5 TT PROB 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I renamed your dictionary from `dict` to `mapper` because `dict` is a built in function. You can get rid of `.astype(str)` if your dictionary would use integers as keys.

```
mapper={
 '1': 'AA',
 '2': 'GG',
 '3': 'AA',
 '4': 'CC',
 '5': 'TT',
 '6': 'AA',
 '7': 'TT',
 '8': 'GG',
 '9': 'CT',
 '10': 'AA'}

df[df.TYPE == df.RS.astype(str).map(mapper)]
```

Out:

```
  VALUE  RS TYPE CONDITION  OTHER_COLUMN  OTHER-COLUMN
0    SS   2   GG      PROB             1             2
4    DD   9   CT    NORMAL             1             2
6    FF   5   TT      PROB             1             2
```

Comment: great @Michael,  thaks in advance, very useful for me